# Can python run threads several times?

Tags: python

I made one button on tkinter.

When you press the button, it will be threaded and output 1.

However, after once, the erotic code is distributed and there is no execution.

What should i do?

main code

```
from tkinter import Tk
import tkinter as tk
import threading

root = tk.Tk()
def test1():
    print("1")

btn1 = tk.Button(root, text="test", command=threading.Thread(target=test1).start)
btn1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

error code

```
File "", line 869 in start
    raise RuntimeError("threads can only be started once")
RuntimeError: threads can only be started once
```

Comment: Make it `command=lambda: threading.Thread(target=test1).start()`. I think it is because you are calling the same thread again and again, but with `lambda` you create a new call to the threaded function each time?

Comment: Thank you so much. I live because of you.